# How to install JavaFx?

Tags: installation, java, application-development

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install JavaFx in Ubuntu 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146162/how-to-install-javafx-in-ubuntu-12-04)

I'm very new to Ubuntu world. I downloaded the JavaFx from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/devpreview-1429449.html). I got a zip file. I don't know how do I setup a classpath for it.

Can anyone help me with this regard?