# How to install JavaFx in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, installation

I download JavaFx from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/devpreview-1429449.html). I placed it in my home directory(`anto`) under the name `javafx`. Then I did something like this :

```
vi ~/.bashrc
```

and added the following lines:

```
javaFx_home=/anto/javafx/rt/lib/jfxrt.jar
export PATH=$PATH:$javaFx_home
```

But after providing the classpath, I tried running :

```
groovy MyProgram
```

(which depends on the JavaFx classpath).

But that throws me an error.  Where I went wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Automatically: (via webupd8 helper ppa repository)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

> **Note:** You can replace `oracle-java7-installer` with `oracle-java8-installer` or `oracle-java9-installer`.  You will need to accept the Oracle End User License Agreement prior to installation (this isn't required with OpenJDK, so if a OpenJDK back-port is released for 12.04, please update this post! :)

Manually:

- http://www.wikihow.com/Install-JavaFX-on-Ubuntu-Linux

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting the `CLASSPATH` instead of `PATH`. Java tries to load it's classes from the locations referenced by `CLASSPATH`.

- First check your existing classpath with `echo $CLASSPATH`. Like `PATH`, the entries for `CLASSPATH` are separated with `:`(colon). The presence of a `.` entry under `CLASSPATH` means `java` can always load classes from current directory.
- To add a `.jar` library to your `CLASSPATH` you should open the file `~/.profile` and add `export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:path to .jar` to it. Like in your case it should be
  `javaFx_home=/home/anto/javafx/rt/lib/jfxrt.jar`
  `export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$javaFx_home`
   if `.` was not present in your previous `CLASSPATH` entry then modify the last line as
  `export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$javaFx_home:.`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I've found so far.

I downloaded JavaFX SDK `1.2` and `2.2`. They have removed some files from JavaFX SDK.

For `1.2`

```
virpara@Ascension:~$ tree -L 2 '/home/virpara/Desktop/javafx-sdk1.2' 
/home/virpara/Desktop/javafx-sdk1.2
|-- bin
|   |-- javafx
|   |-- javafxc
|   |-- javafxdoc
|   `-- javafxpackager
|-- COPYRIGHT.html
|-- docs
|   |-- api
|   |-- emulator.html
|   |-- index.html
|   |-- javafxc.html
|   |-- javafxdoc.html
|   |-- javafx.html
|   |-- javafxpackager.html
|   `-- manpage.css
|-- emulator
|   `-- bin
|-- invoice.properties
|-- lib
|   |-- desktop
|   |-- javafx-runtime.properties
|   |-- mobile
|   `-- shared
|-- LICENSE.txt
|-- profiles
|   |-- desktop.properties
|   `-- mobile.properties
|-- README.html
|-- samples
|   |-- DisplayShelf
|   |-- DisplayShelfMobile
|   |-- DragAndDrop
|   |-- index.html
|   |-- InterestingPhotos
|   |-- LocalSearch
|   |-- MediaBox
|   |-- PathAnimation
|   |-- PhotoEffects
|   |-- PhotoFlip
|   |-- shared
|   `-- SpringAnimation
|-- servicetag
|   `-- registration.jar
|-- src.zip
|-- THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.txt
`-- timestamp

23 directories, 23 files
```

For `2.2`

```
virpara@Ascension:~$ tree -L 2 '/home/virpara/Desktop/javafx-sdk2.2.0-beta' 
/home/virpara/Desktop/javafx-sdk2.2.0-beta
|-- bin
|   `-- javafxpackager
|-- COPYRIGHT.html
|-- docs
|   `-- api
|-- lib
|   |-- ant-javafx.jar
|   |-- javafx-doclet.jar
|   `-- javafx-mx.jar
|-- README.html
|-- rt
|   |-- COPYRIGHT.html
|   |-- lib
|   |-- README.html
|   `-- THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.txt
`-- THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.txt

6 directories, 10 files
```

There is only `javafxpackager` script in `javafx-sdk2.2.0-beta/bin` (`javafx, javafxc, javafxdoc` scripts are removed) it means that if you export `javafx-sdk2.2.0-beta/bin` to your `PATH` variable and try to execute `javafx --version` in terminal it can't find `javafx` because there is no executable named `javafx`.

Well I've no experience with JavaFX but probably they have removed other three scripts because it would not be needed and perhaps `javafxpackager` would do the thing or `java` is enough for that.

You've tried to include whole path to `jfxrt.jar` to `PATH` variable.

it won't work because it can't automatically pass to `-cp` parameter. So, you must give full path to `jfxrt.jar` as `-cp /anto/javafx/rt/lib/jfxrt.jar`

```
java -cp /anto/javafx/rt/lib/jfxrt.jar MyProgram.java
```

*I know it is not a solution.*

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and **@samik answer works for me** !

Into my `~.bashrc` , like @samik say :

```
export JAVAFX_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/javafx-sdk2.2.0-beta/rt/lib/jfxrt.jar
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$JAVAFX_HOME:.
```

Now a little `source .profile` and we try with an example

```
touch JavaFxText.java
```

I cut/copy this example code into the file :

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.effect.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * Simple demonstration of JavaFX text support.
 * 
 * @author Dustin
 */
public class JavaFxText extends Application
{
   /**
    * Start demonstration of JavaFX text capabilities.
    * 
    * @param stage Stage for JavaFX application.
    * @throws Exception Exception in JavaFX application.
    */
   @Override
   public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception
   {
      stage.setTitle("Simplistic Example of JavaFX 2.0 Text Capabilities");
      final Group rootGroup = new Group();
      final Scene scene =
         new Scene(rootGroup, 800, 400, Color.BEIGE);

      final Text text1 = new Text(25, 25, "(2007) JavaFX based on F3");
      text1.setFill(Color.CHOCOLATE);
      text1.setFont(Font.font(java.awt.Font.SERIF, 25));
      rootGroup.getChildren().add(text1);

      final Text text2 = new Text(25, 50, "(2010) JavaFX Script Deprecated");
      text2.setFill(Color.DARKBLUE);
      text2.setFont(Font.font(java.awt.Font.SANS_SERIF, 30));
      rootGroup.getChildren().add(text2);

      final Text text3 = new Text(25, 75, "(2011) JavaFX to be Open Sourced!");
      text3.setFill(Color.TEAL);
      text3.setFont(Font.font(java.awt.Font.MONOSPACED, 35));
      rootGroup.getChildren().add(text3);

      final Text text4 = new Text(25, 125, "(2011) JavaFX to be Standardized");
      text4.setFill(Color.CRIMSON);
      text4.setFont(Font.font(java.awt.Font.DIALOG, 40));
      final Effect glow = new Glow(1.0);
      text4.setEffect(glow);
      rootGroup.getChildren().add(text4);

      final Text text5 = new Text(25, 175, "(Now) Time for JavaFX 2.0!");
      text5.setFill(Color.DARKVIOLET);
      text5.setFont(Font.font(java.awt.Font.SERIF, FontWeight.EXTRA_BOLD, 45));
      final Light.Distant light = new Light.Distant();
      light.setAzimuth(-135.0);
      final Lighting lighting = new Lighting();
      lighting.setLight(light);
      lighting.setSurfaceScale(9.0);
      text5.setEffect(lighting);
      rootGroup.getChildren().add(text5);

      final Text text6 = new Text(25, 225, "JavaFX News at JavaOne!");
      text6.setFill(Color.DARKGREEN);
      text6.setBlendMode(BlendMode.COLOR_BURN);
      text6.setFont(Font.font(java.awt.Font.DIALOG_INPUT, FontWeight.THIN, 45));
      final Reflection reflection = new Reflection();
      reflection.setFraction(1.0);
      text6.setEffect(reflection);
      rootGroup.getChildren().add(text6);

      stage.setScene(scene);
      stage.show();
   }

   /**
    * Main JavaFX application launching method.
    * 
    * @param arguments Command-line arguments: none expected.
    */
   public static void main(final String[] arguments)
   {
      Application.launch(arguments);
   }
}
```

And it's running

```
javac JavaFxText.java
java JavaFxText
```

Give the bounty to @samik, he deserves !!