# Ubuntu 12.04 version of Netbeans doesn't have the JavaFX plugin

Tags: software-center, java, netbeans

I just want to know why does Netbeans 7.0.1 from the official Ubuntu 12.04 doesn't have all the plugins (in especial the JavaFX plugin) on it while the official Netbeans from the website (even the version with the less plugin), has it by default ?

And how can we change that ?

Because I love Ubuntu (even if it is extremly slow on my Asus 1215N (it is the only OS that is slow on it, but that's not very important), but I am trying to use it only with the software provided by the Original repositories without having to download manually or even use any PPA.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/146162/how-to-install-javafx-in-ubuntu-12-04

Answer (score 1):

[JavaFX is currently proprietary software](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=JavaFX&oldid=519797879#License), which means it is not part of the open-source OpenJDK, and prevents Ubuntu from redistributing it in the official repositories. The Netbeans plugin is presumably omitted (though the Netbeans plugin itself is open-source) because it would be useless without the JavaFX runtime.

In 2011, Oracle announced plans to open-source JavaFX as the [OpenJFX project](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/openjfx/). It appears that thus far only some parts have been released. According to [Oracle's JavaFX roadmap](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/roadmap-1446331.html):

> The OpenJFX project was launched in December 2011, with the JavaFX UI Controls source code being contributed initially; the rest of JavaFX is planned to follow by the end of 2012.

Once that happens, it could be included with Ubuntu's Java platform.

Comment: I hope they will do the same for the runtime. Thank you for the information :D